# JS/HTML Image changer with dynamic img src

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, dynamic

Essentially I'm adding some JS to a site that allows the same set of buttons to load images(colour options) based on the ONLY image found within an ID.  WIP to illustrate:
http://www.twistfurniture.co/collections/product-test/

So what I've done thus far:

```
<div id="switchgallery">
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/Chair.jpg" id="switchimage">
</div>

<p>        
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Show black" onclick="ShowBlack()"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Show red" onclick="ShowRed()"/>
</p>
```

JS

```
function ShowBlack() 
{document.getElementById("switchimage").src = "/wp-content/uploads/Chair_Black.jpg";}

function ShowRed() 
{document.getElementById("switchimage").src = "/wp-content/uploads/Chair_Red.jpg";}
```

Now this works but if I have lots of colours and lots of products it'll take ages and require coding each time a new product is adding (productname=Chair in the above example).

What I'd like to accomplish is the following.

```
function ShowBlack() 
{document.getElementById("switchimage").src = "***Dynamically generate the SRC of the image based on the ID of switchimage and and add _Black before the file extension =(/wp-content/uploads/Chair_Black.jpg)***";}
```

That way I can add lots of products and so long as they have the correct ID and the buttons are on the page I will get an easy method to switch their colour (assuming I have uploaded the appropriately named files in the right directory ;D)

Like I mentioned this is a work in progress and I will continue to fiddle until either I solve this myself or you guys flip over the ICT Hero card.

I've learned a lot by reading these forums, but now need direct assistance! Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your site is a Word Press site, I would recommend using one of the many plugins available, like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-catalogue/).

While I will be the first to want to use my own custom code, Word Press plugins are the best way to work within Word Press.  While it may seem straight forward, there are a lot of things to consider. For example, how to determine what the product is and what images are available for said product.  Javascript is a client side library and won't give you the best solution for something like a product catalog unless you have full control over the site.

Comment: I will admit that the Plugins can be great on Wordpress, but I felt that this was a nice little step for me to get to grips with a mini Javascript Project and learn a little more.  I will give the plugin linked a shot.

At the very least I hope the excellent answers provided above help somebody perhaps using a blank canvas and not Cheatpress :P

Comment: @user2933771 I feel obligated to respond with, *Use the best tool for the job* :)

Comment: There is a tool for every job and a job for every tool ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to setup a function with a parameter color :

```
function showImage(color) {
    document.getElementById("switchimage").src = "/wp-content/uploads/Chair_"+color+".jpg";
}
```

this color can easily be a parameter of the button that you load with a function like that

```
function showImage() {
{
     var color = jQuery(this).attr("color");
     document.getElementById("switchimage").src = "/wp-content/uploads/Chair_"+color+".jpg";
}
```

with button definition like

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Show black" onclick="showImage()" color="black"/>
```

Comment: Ah I wasn't even close! I think I understand the process you've used, I presume if no colour is selected/no button is click so long as there is a Chair_.jpg file (based on your example) - that will still load?  IE a default image.

Cheers for that aerfevre - looks spot on, I'll implement now :)

Comment: On page loading, you may already set up a default image.
then on click, you can add whatever rule of image naming you want ;)

Comment: Ah yeah that'll be whats in the HTML - it wont be until the Javascript is 'triggered' on the buttons that anything will happen.

Understand now, On your second quote theres two {{ at the start, do I need another one at the end to close things off?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function ShowBlack() 
{
  source = document.getElementById("switchimage").src;
  if (source.lastIndexOf("_") != -1){
    source = source.substring(0,source.lastIndexOf("_"));
  }else{
    source = source.substring(0,source.lastIndexOf("."));
  }
  source += "_Black.jpg"
  console.log(source);
  document.getElementById("switchimage").src = source;
}

function ShowRed() 
{
  source = document.getElementById("switchimage").src;
  if (source.lastIndexOf("_") != -1){
    source = source.substring(0,source.lastIndexOf("_"));
  }
  else{
    source = source.substring(0,source.lastIndexOf("."));
  }
  source += "_Red.jpg"
  document.getElementById("switchimage").src = source;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TQhJk/1/

Comment: This works nicely, I added another function and changed Black to Red too - they both worked so long as they were the first ones click, I had to rerun the fiddle for the other to work - I'll try it on a live site as fiddle doesn't seem to like me :)

Thank you very much for the swift response here - fantastic support!

Comment: I have updated my answer to suite your needs better, provided the image path does contain underscores. I have also updated the fiddle

Comment: Used this solution in the end, it seemed to work the best across browsers and devices.  Annoyingly the image that is generated cannot be zoomed or opened in a lightbox as it opens the original default image - sad times but still a great solution ty

Comment: Please accept as your answer so your question does not show up on unanswered. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1. Use data.
   You can use the data attribute to store which color to load.

   `<button data-color="Red">Red</button>`

   jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PThwj/
2. Use arguments

   `<button onlick="loadImage('black');">Black</button>`

   jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gt6BS/1/

The load image function looks like this:

```
function loadImage(color) {
    document.querySelector("#image").innerHTML = 
        "/wp-content/uploads/Chair_" + color;
    // Change source of image here by using img.src
}
```

To bind events dynamically (if you use option 1) do this:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".chair-button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", loadImageEvent);
}
```

Now you can add `<button>`s and specify a `data-color` and the rest will take care of itself.

Comment: It's interesting how there are so many ways to achieve similar/the same results.  Whilst the other methods posted are easier for me to get my bonce around I'll try to implement yours on a test site to learn from the efforts you've made - cheers for the answer!